# Xcode 4: nib files not loading when run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

So, I just downloaded Xcode 4 and installed it. I was actually quite looking forward to the single window and integrated IB...

-

However, when I open and run one of my projects, the nib files that the project uses don't seem to load. Instead I'm left looking at a blank white screen (iPhone). This project ran well and fine on Xcode 3.2.

If I background and un-background the app, the view loads fine. But this happens every time I build, on both iPhone and iOS simulator, i.e. the app doesn't work properly until it's been backgrounded. All the code for loading the view follows from

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application.
```

-

Did anyone else have the same nib file problems - is there a fix (or something stupidly simple that I'm forgetting about)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a lot of messing around, I figured out the nib problem.

I had a stray line of code in the appDelegate class:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

This line of code doesn't affect anything when compiling with Xcode 3.2, but with Xcode 4 causes the loading problem. Just remove it (I don't even remember why it was there...) and it's fixed :)

Comment: Same problem, same line of code.  Removing this line fixes it.  Thanks, you probably saved my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on with your nibs, but [this XCode 4 transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) should be of some help for finding missing panels, menus etc...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  In my case, for some reason Xcode had decided to hide the view in question.  It cleared up when I put the following into the viewDidAppear method of the view controller:

```
self.view.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same error. If upper won't help - check if you did not overwrite the **view** attribute of your `ViewController`.